# M1 or M2 for masters in Mathematics for Engineering background

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters, germany, france

I want to apply for master's program in mathematics in France. I have a dual degree (M.Tech+B.Tech in 5 years) in Electrical engineering but my master's thesis was complexity theory in learning machines and most of the course are in applied mathematics.

I graduated 5 years ago and now I have been doing pure math since the last 3 years on my own, attending different course in different universities while doing job as well. I have applied to US universities for PhD but I doubt will get in. So, now I am looking for master's options in France and Germany. For Germany I think I can clearly see that I can't do masters due to the fact that I have missed the scholarships deadline. I had applied to University of Bonn but they outrightly rejected me saying that your first degree must be in mathematics.

So, I am hoping for masters in France but I am not able to find scholarships and I am not sure whether the same condition applies to French system as well.

[Q-1] Does one need to have a first degree in Mathematics to apply to M1 or M2?

[Q-2] In case if I can apply, can I directly apply to M2 without applying for M1? (I have seen some of the answers which says that they require you to go through M1 before moving to M2. It is a must. If it is, then I have no issue going through it)

[Q-3] Does anyone know of scholarships that's available to Indian nationality for applying to the above programs.

Which universities in France or anywhere (decent enough) can I apply to for master's? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1: My Interest is in Algebraic geometry and Complex geometry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [M1 vs M2 in France: In the French system, which one is designed for those interested in Academia, M1 or M2?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/106647/m1-vs-m2-in-france-in-the-french-system-which-one-is-designed-for-those-intere)

Comment: @ArnaudD. The user in the question already has a math degree. It does answer [Q-2] to some extent but the only problem is that in that, I cannot find what is actually  " equivalent of M1".

Comment: 'Equivalent to M1' is up to the university to decide, there are no hard rules. The university has to be convinced that your qualifications are equivalent.

Comment: @quarague Can I contact the program administrator to know whether I have covered M1? Or Do I have to apply directly and wait for acceptance or rejection for M2?

Comment: You can contact them and ask whether your qualifications are sufficient and how they evaluate that. However, if your case is not clear cut, they might just tell you that you have to send a full application so they can consider all the details.